# how to print only numbers from a file which contains alphanumerics unix

Tags: linux, shell, unix

how to print only numbers from a file which contains alphanumerics unix
My file is:
cat test1.txt

matrix id from the HP Asset manager THIS LINE IS THE 1ST UPPER CASE LINE IN THIS FILE.
this line is the 1st lower case line in this file.
This Line Has All Its First Character Of The Word With Upper Case.

Two lines above this line is empty.
And this is the last line.

```
Sainadh 9876543210 YWC
avinash 9871234560 kvan
lalith 9875463210 mlp
sudgaeaed 9875645612 kkk
jknlnklm dasdad 9871239875
9879879876 uuojlx 987897654322
cknkzxnckl 9873456541 kkdlsd
```

Iwant o/p like

```
9876543210 
9871234560 
9875463210 
9875645612 
9871239875
987897654322
9879879876 
9873456541
```

TIA

Comment: How would you do by hand? This is the first step to find an algorithm...

Answer (score 3):

```
grep -Eo "\b[0-9]+\b" filename
```

`[0-9]+` means 1 or more digits
and inside `\b` `\b` matches only that lines that contain that value form word.

Answer (score 0):

grep -ow .[0-9]* test1.txt

```
  -o, --only-matching
          Print only the matched (non-empty) parts  of  a  matching  line,
          with each such part on a separate output line.
  -w, --word-regexp
          Select  only  those  lines  containing  matches  that form whole
          words.  The test is that the matching substring must  either  be
          at  the  beginning  of  the  line,  or  preceded  by  a non-word
          constituent character.  Similarly, it must be either at the  end
          of  the  line  or  followed by a non-word constituent character.
          Word-constituent  characters  are  letters,  digits,   and   the
          underscore.
```